# Sqoop Import Fails

Tags: sqoop

I'm trying to import a Table from Oracle to Hive using Sqoop. I used the following command:

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:<connection> --table test1 --username test --password test --hive-table hive_test --create-hive-table --hive-import -m 1
```

But this gives me the error

```
 Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory <hdfs path> already exists
```

So I read online in many forums and it said that I should delete the directory and run the command again. 
I did exactly that, but I still keep getting the error.

Comment: does the table already  exists ? if so you need to use --hive-overwrite

Comment: The table does not exist, that's why I'm using --create-hive-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand working of Sqoop hive Import.

- Import data to HDFS `<some-dir>`
- Create hive table `<some-table>` IF NOT EXISTS
- LOAD data inpath '`<some-dir>`' into table `<some-table>`

You are getting the error at step 1.

```
Output directory <hdfs path> already exists
```

Delete this `<hdfs path>` and proceed.

**Better way:**

No need to delete this manually everytime.

Use `--delete-target-dir` in the command. It will

> Delete the import target directory if it exists

***P.S.** No need to use `--create-hive-table` with `--hive-import`. `--hive-import` by default create table for you.*

Answer (score 0):

Hive store its Table data in hive warehouse on hdfs with table name as directory and usually have below path

**/user/hive/warehouse/**

need to delete table name directory.

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/hive/warehouse/hive_test
```